# Virtualenv doesn't work on RedHat

Tags: python, virtualenv, redhat, fedora

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot create a virtualenv on RedHat. Here's my command line :

```
python /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/virtualenv-2.7 -p /opt/rh/python27/ /home/myuser/tpa/
```

.

```
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/virtualenv-2.7 : Is here to setup the version of virtualenv that I want to use

-p /opt/rh/python27/  : To setup the version of python I want to use

/home/myuser/tpa/ : My directory where the virtualenv will be stored
```

But I get the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/virtualenv-2.7", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.10.1
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You should precise a python executable path after -p option and not a directory. Ex: /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-p expects a python executable, not an installation directory. Give it the name of a python executable in your $PATH or the full path the the python executable you want to run.